# Is .NET Core 3.1 backward compatible?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to know if .NET Core 3.1 is backward compatible with .NET Core 2.1. I am getting below error while adding a nuget package(say package X) targeting .netcoreapp2.1 to my .netcoreapp3.1 project:

NU1202: Package  is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package  supports: netcore21 (.NETCore,Version=v2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the TFM `netcore21` is not .NET Core 2.1.
Because the TFM `netcorexx` has been taken by some former deprecated platform that used to be called ".NET Core", which is not the well known .NET Core at all.

The proper TFM for .NET Core is `netcoreappx.x` (to be distinguished from the deprecated platform).

Thus this is irrelative to backward compatibility problem. And the nuget package that you are trying to add does not ever target any version of .NET Core.